# Explain the difference between extrapolation and interpolation

Tags: box2d, physics, fixed-timestep

http://www.unagames.com/blog/daniele/2010/06/fixed-time-step-implementation-box2d here there are two algorithms of smoothing in case of fixed time step physics simulation. I don't understand the formula of interpolation:

```
state = currentState * alpha + previousState * (1-alpha)
```

And also I don't understand the comparison figure. Please explaing what is the meaning of multiplying `current state` with `alpha` and summing with `previous state` with `1 - alpha`.

Comment: If you sum `alpha` and `1-alpha` you get a `1`. That is we take 2 parts of something and take percentages from them that in sum gives us 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part 1: Interpolation:**

Interpolation **let's us approximate** something that already happened. Multiplying "trick" (which is just math) is to mix the previous state with the current state by a certain percentage. If previous was dark and now is bright, we assume in the middle it was grey.

So if for example we take a moving train. We know that right now it is 56km from London and an hour ago it was 140km from London, knowing these two positions (A and B) and a time between them - 1 hour, we can interpolate between them and know the trains position at any given time between now and an hour ago.

For example, we want to know trains position 15min ago. That is 15min ago from now and 45 min after an hour ago timestamp. When we need to mix 2 values, we need to sum them, each multiplied by it's proportion in the final result. Whole sum is 100%, that means that if one value is 25%, then the other one is 100% - 25% = 75%. So we make our formula

```
140 * 0.25 + 56 * (1 - 0.25) = 77
```

77km is the how far away from London our train was 15min ago iw we calculate that using linear interpolation.

Another approach to the case is if we rewrite the formula to be

```
Result = A + (B - A) * alpha
```

It has the same effect, but a slightly different explanation. We take the point A and add to it a difference between points A and B multiplied by the proportion. Repeating our example,

```
140 + (56 - 140) * 0.75 = 77
```

```
  A--------------------I------B------------London
140km                 77km   56km            0km
```

**Part 2: Extrapolation**

Extrapolation means that **we try to predict** something, knowing how it behaved in the past. Let's reuse the same example with the train. We know the train passed -84km (56-140) in last hour, so we can *assume* that in the next hour the train will pass the same, and the next hour, and the next (of course if we assume it passes through London without a stop, that's the weakness of the extrapolation, like any other prediction it's inaccurate). Anyway, if we need to guess the trains position 15 min in the future, we do:

```
Result = B + (B - A) * alpha = 56 + (56 - 140) * 0.25 = 35
```

Train will be 35km to London.

```
  A---------------------------B-----E------London
140km                        56km  35km      0km
```

*Note:*

Interpolation formula can be used to extrapolate, if we allow alpha to be outside of 0..1 range, e.g. for case 2 we can write is as being 25% of time in another direction (alpha becomes negative):

```
Result := A * alpha + B * (1 - alpha)
Result := 140 * -0.25 + 56 * (1 - -0.25) = -35 + 70 = 35
```

Comment: What you wrote I completely understand. In your example you talk about 15 minutes ago not 15 minutes after. This is what I don't understand. Otherwise you example is very clear. If you know where it was 1 hour ago and where it is now you can say where it was 15 minutes ago. But you can not say where it will be 15 after. But in this article with deal with a time ahead of current state.

Comment: I'm expanding the answer. Anything needed to be clarified?

Comment: I understand how extrapolation tries to predict the future position. But I don't understand how interpolation tries to predict the future. In your example you predict the result 15 minutes ago - in the past. But in the article they predict 15 minutes after, right?

Comment: Extrapolation predicts future ("Extra" means "out, outside"). Interpolation does not predicts future, it *reveals* past ("Intra" means "in, within")

Comment: Please look at this loop in the article: `for (int i = 0; i < nStepsClamped; ++ i)` In it the last physics step is done and also there is some reminding time in `fixedTimestepAccumulator_`. This time is ahead of physics time. It is the rendering time, right? So why do we use the time (or ratio - `fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio_`) that is ahead of the last physics time to calculate the position between previous and last physics steps? I hope you understand what is my concern here.

Comment: I guess there is a trick here. We should consider that Physics World is being shifted on step behind artificially to adjust position in "past" - to interpolate.

Comment: Shifting one step behind is a known trick to allow to use interpolation for smooth visualization. I'll be expanding the answer too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18927/discussion-between-narek-and-krom-stern).